# Typo in the french ed. of Bourbaki General Topology Ch.1 section 4.1?

Tags: general-topology

See the attached excerpt from French edition Bourbaki General Topology Ch.1 Section 4.1. I know almost nothing about French but I feel the third line not quite meaningful. Should it actually have written with the "de" and "$\mapsto$" interchanged? And even so, its english translation (mine) "... the product function $f:(x_i)\mapsto(f_i(x_i))$ of $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ into $\Pi_{i\in I}Y_i$ be continuous at a point $a=(a_i)$, ..." seems to be not a usual way of writing in English.

Question: if there is a typo and if so, how to fix and its English translation.

Thanks.

[image: Bourbaki General Topology Ch.1 Section 4.1]

Comment: My language is french and I approve: there is indeed an interchange. Translation: "In order that the product mapping $x_i \mapsto f(x_i) $ from $\Pi X_i \to \Pi Y_i$ is continuous in a point ... it is necessary and sufficient that... for all $i \in I$,  $f_i$ is continuous in..."

Comment: By the way, the result is false. If one of the $X_i$ is empty, then $f$ is always continuous because its domain is empty. Okay, perhaps a bit nitpicky ... but Bourbaki is usually precise.

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't have the set theory volume to check it, but maybe a "famille d'espaces" already implies non-empty sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am not sure about the emptiness of a space, but my impression is that a "family" is a "function", and a function could have its domain empty, and in such case the range empty as well. That said, this is only about the emptiness of the _collection_ of the spaces, but not about each individual space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Actually after I read the original text again, it seems that emptiness of a set (or space), say, $X_k$, should not be a problem even if a space could be empty, becase in such case no point $a = (a_i)$ exists. In other words, the statement says $\forall a=(a_i) [(f \mbox{ continuous at } a) \Leftrightarrow (\forall i\in I f_i \mbox{ continuous at } a_i)]$, which is trivially true when $a$ does not exist.

Comment: @ALife If no $a$ exists, then $f$ is trivially continuous. But this does not allow to conclude that all $f_i$  are continuous. In fact they can be arbitrary functions. But of course the continuity of all $f_i$ always implies the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I believe I understood your point that you already said in the first post, and your statement is true. My point is, however, that the statement in the original text is not exactly the same as yours; instead it probably means what I said above, i.e., $\forall a=(a_i) [ ... ]$. The difference is subtle though.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite meaningful IMHO. The interchange does make it a bit more logical. But it’s still quite clear.

Starting with "Pour que" it says roughly:

> In order for the product map $f$, defined by mapping $(x_i)_i$ to $f_i(x_i)_i$, from $\prod_{i \in I}X_i $ into $\prod_{i \in I} Y_i$ to be continuous at a point $(a_i)_i$, it is necessary and sufficient that for **all** $i \in I$, $f_i$ be continuous at $a_i$.

Seems perfectly clear and precise to me.

Comment: would you mind explaining the role of "de" (presumably meaning "of") and $\mapsto$ in the original text (i.e., without interchange)?

Comment: @ALife De arrow would have been more logical between $(x_i)$ and its result, and "de" before $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$. It's clearly what is meant.

Comment: ok, so you meant that the original text indeed has typo, but it's meaningful to you after the interchange. If so, I agree. I believe I knew what the text wanted to say (assuming the typo), but (if read literally) it does not seem to be a common way to say what it wants to say, even though I've read multiple other volumes of Bourbaki and 10+ other textbooks in general topology.

Comment: @ALife books are full of typos. Even Bourbaki's. Not sure what year my edition is. I bought them in Paris, a long time ago. Books are cheaper there.

Comment: Certainly, that's why I posted here in the first place. My edition is 3-540-33936-1 with the following edition info: Réimpression inchangée de l’édition originale de 1971 © Hermann, Paris, 1971
© N. Bourbaki, 1981
© Masson, Paris, 1981
© N. Bourbaki et Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2007. What about yours? No such typo?

Comment: Btw, if you actually meant the interchange **is indeed needed**, then you probably want to edit your answer to avoid confusing others.

Comment: The interchange is indeed a **necessity**, as I clearly said upwards. You cannot say "does make it a little bit more logical".